# Asterisk: pri to pri connection. Green light but a lot of hdlc errors

Tags: asterisk

I want to connect(for learning, nothing serious), two asterisk server via ISDN PRI.
The first server will act as "telco" so is pri_net, the second server is the cpe, so I will use pri_cpe.

The cards are

pbx1-net: Digium TE205P
pbx2-cpe: Openvox D210P

Both servers/pbx use Debian 11 and dahdi 2.11 drivers

On the pbx-net this is dahdi/system.conf

```
    # Span 1: WCTDM/4 "Wildcard TDM400P REV E/F Board 5" (MASTER) 
    fxoks=1
    echocanceller=mg2,1
    fxoks=2
    echocanceller=mg2,2
    # channel 3, WCTDM/4/2, no module.
    fxsks=4
    echocanceller=mg2,4
    
    # Span 2: TE2/0/1 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" 
    span=2,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
    # termtype: te
    bchan=5-19,21-35
    dchan=20
    echocanceller=mg2,5-19,21-35
    
    # Span 3: TE2/0/2 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" 
    span=3,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
    # termtype: te
    bchan=36-50,52-66
    dchan=51
    echocanceller=mg2,36-50,52-66
    
    # Global data
    
    loadzone    = it
    defaultzone = it
```

this is the /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf on pbx-net

```
    [trunkgroups]
    [channels]
    language=it
    context=local
    switchtype=euroisdn
    signalling=pri_net
    usecallerid=yes
    hidecallerid=no
    callwaiting=yes
    usecallingpres=yes
    callwaitingcallerid=yes
    threewaycalling=yes
    transfer=yes    ;se usi nt ptmp metti no
    canpark=yes
    cancallforward=yes
    callreturn=yes
    context=local
    echocancel=yes
    channel => 1-15,17-31
    echocancelwhenbridged=yes
    group=1
    callgroup=1
    pickupgroup=1
    immediate=no
    #include /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf
```

This is the /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf on pbx-net

```
; Span 1: WCTDM/4 "Wildcard TDM400P REV E/F Board 5" (MASTER) 
;;; line="1 WCTDM/4/0"
signalling=fxo_ks
callerid="Channel 1" <4001>
mailbox=4001
group=5
context=from-dahdi
channel => 1

;;; line="2 WCTDM/4/1"
signalling=fxo_ks
callerid="Channel 2" <4002>
mailbox=4002
group=5
context=from-dahdi
channel => 2

;;; line="4 WCTDM/4/3"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=0
context=from-dahdi
channel => 4

; Span 2: TE2/0/1 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" 
group=0,12
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = pri_net
channel => 5-19,21-35

; Span 3: TE2/0/2 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" 
group=0,13
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = pri_net
channel => 36-50,52-66
```

On the pbx-cpe side, the files are identical except for /etc/dahdi/system.conf (the 1,1,0 is 1: span 1: timing sourcing from pri_net side, 0: cable is 0-133feet)

```
# Span 1: TE2/0/1 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" (MASTER) 
span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3
# termtype: te
bchan=1-15,17-31
dchan=16
echocanceller=mg2,1-15,17-31

# Span 2: TE2/0/2 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" 
span=2,2,0,ccs,hdb3
# termtype: te
bchan=32-46,48-62
dchan=47
echocanceller=mg2,32-46,48-62

# Global data

loadzone        = it
defaultzone     = it
```

The other two files are identical, except for pri_net which became pri_cpe.

Now the problem:

On pri_cpe bpx the cli report is OK

```
dahdi show status
    Description                              Alarms  IRQ    bpviol CRC    Fra Codi Options  LBO
    T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1                OK      0      0      0      CCS HDB3          0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
```

On pri_net bpx the cli report is OK

```
dahdi show status
Description                              Alarms  IRQ    bpviol CRC    Fra Codi Options  LBO
Wildcard TDM400P REV E/F Board 5         OK      0      0      0      CAS Unk           0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1                OK      0      0      0      CCS HDB3 CRC4     0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2                OK      0      0      0      CCS HDB3 CRC4     0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)
```

Also pri span report ok on both sides

net_side

```
pri show spans
PRI span 2/0: Up, Active
```

cpe_side

```
pri show spans
PRI span 1/0: Up, Active
```

I configured extensions.conf to call via the pri on both sides

```
[uscita]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(dahdi/g12/${EXTEN})
exten => _X.,n,Hangup
```

When I try to made a call on both consoles appear those error messages

On pri_net side
[May  1 18:57:50] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2

On pri_cpe side

```
[May  1 18:58:07] NOTICE[1489]: chan_dahdi.c:2777 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 1
[May  1 18:58:07] NOTICE[1489]: chan_dahdi.c:2777 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 1
[May  1 18:58:07] NOTICE[1489]: chan_dahdi.c:2777 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 1
```

again on pri_net side

```
== Primary D-Channel on span 2 down
[May  1 18:59:32] WARNING[2541]: sig_pri.c:1212 pri_find_dchan: Span 2: D-channel is down!
[May  1 18:59:33] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 18:59:40] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 18:59:42] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 18:59:43] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 18:59:43] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 18:59:45] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2
  == Primary D-Channel on span 2 up
[May  1 18:59:58] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 18:59:58] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 18:59:59] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2
    -- Registered SIP 'telefono3' at 192.168.0.2:59897
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [511@local:1] Dial("SIP/telefono3-00000000", "dahdi/g12/511") in new stack
    -- Requested transfer capability: 0x00 - SPEECH
    -- Called dahdi/g12/511
[May  1 19:00:09] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 2
  == Primary D-Channel on span 2 down
[May  1 19:00:10] WARNING[2541]: sig_pri.c:1212 pri_find_dchan: Span 2: D-channel is down!
[May  1 19:00:11] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 2
  == Primary D-Channel on span 2 up
    -- Span 2: Channel 0/1 got hangup, cause 18
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i2/511-1'
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Executing [511@local:2] Hangup("SIP/telefono3-00000000", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (local, 511, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/telefono3-00000000'
[May  1 19:00:18] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Bad FCS (8) on D-channel of span 2
[May  1 19:00:21] NOTICE[2541]: chan_dahdi.c:2780 my_handle_dchan_exception: Got DAHDI event: HDLC Abort (6) on D-channel of span 2
```

I try those solutions

```
Solution number 1: the card is broken, I bought another PRI card = FAIL
Solution number 2: change the pci slot of card pri_net side, and / or pri_cpe side = FAIL
Solution number 3: use a different dahdi version = FAIL
Solution number 4: use pridiallocalplan=unknown and pridialplan=unknown = FAIL
Solution number 5: revert pri_net pri_cpe roles = FAIL
Solution number 6: try another crossover cable = FAIL(I try 3 cables, two bought, one made by me, and all tested with network tester)
Solution number 7: reboot = FAIL
Solution number 8: remove the analog card from pci_net server = FAIL
```

Anyone has some suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
Was the cable bad, I follow [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qq8eWs49Gko) on youtube for make the pri cable and works perfect, I had only to reboot the pri_net machine.